# Is there a way to call sp_spaceused in a WHILE loop?

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase

A legacy Sybase script moves records from production to archive in 1000-row batches, but it does not check for space exhaustion on the archive. Is there a way, maybe by calling sp_spaceused, to terminate the loop if the destination is 98% full?

Edit: Yes, this is a symptom of a bigger problem, namely *capacity planning*, but so far my efforts to invoke FORCE PLAN on those who ought to be planning has not resulted in any detectable increase of their planning activity.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on my Sybase, but I don't think you can select values from `sp_spaceused`. It sounds like this is a symptom of a bigger problem: capacity planning. I've run `sp_spaceused` every time before or after an archive job is run daily to keep an eye on storage space. If you don't have room for the data, you shouldn't find that out during the archiving itself!

Comment: You can just grab the pertinent parts of `sp_spaceused`, and include the logic in your batch job.

Comment: @MichaelGardner - I think the question is actually *how* would you "grab the pertinent parts of `sp_spaceused`".